# Extract substrings starting with specific character until next space

Tags: regex, r

I want to extract the tags (twitter handles) from tweets.

```
tweet <- "@me bla bla bla bla @2_him some text @me_"
```

The following only extracts part of some substrings due to the punctuation in some tags

```
regmatches(tweet, gregexpr("@[[:alnum:]]*", tweet))[[1]]
[1] "@me" "@2"  "@me"
```

I don't know what regular expression would return the entire string (@tag).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match all non-spaces, just use the corresponding regular expression

```
regmatches(tweet, gregexpr("@[^ ]*", tweet))[[1]]
# [1] "@me"    "@2_him" "@me_"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following. `\S` will match any non-white space character. As well, you want to use the `+` quantifier instead of `*` otherwise you will end up matching the `@` character by itself if one did exist in the string.

```
> regmatches(tweet, gregexpr("@\\S+", tweet))[[1]]
# [1] "@me"    "@2_him" "@me_"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `[[:alnum:]]*` use `\w*` because `_` does not comes under alphanumeric character list(ie, `[[:alnum:]]` matches  alphanumeric`[A-Za-z0-9]` characters. ) but it comes under word character (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) list.

```
> regmatches(tweet, gregexpr("@\\w*", tweet))[[1]]
[1] "@me"    "@2_him" "@me_"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `qdapRegex` package has a function specifically designed for this task `rm_tag`:

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_tag(tweet, extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "@me"    "@2_him" "@me_"
```